# Flutter: This expression has a type 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call `deleteToDo()` and `editToDo()` which both remove or edit an item in a To Do list. I am using the slidable flutter pub to format the To Do list. However this error is displaying ' This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.'
[image]

I have tried editing it to `Future <Void>` but then get the following error also:
Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

**my dart file:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:best_before/ShoppingList/toDoClass.dart';
import 'package:best_before/ShoppingList/toDos.dart';
import 'package:best_before/ShoppingList/Utils.dart';

class ToDoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ToDo toDo;

  const ToDoWidget({
    required this.toDo,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        child: Slidable(
          key: Key(toDo.id),
          startActionPane: ActionPane(
            motion:  ScrollMotion(),
            dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {}),
            children:  [
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: deleteToDo(context,toDo),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                icon: Icons.delete,
                label: 'Delete',
              ),
            ],
        
          ),
          endActionPane: ActionPane(
          motion: ScrollMotion(),
          children: [
           SlidableAction(
             flex: 2,
             onPressed: editToDo(context, toDo),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              icon: Icons.edit,
              label:'Edit'
            )
          ],
          ),
         child:buildTodo(context),
        ),
      );


  Widget buildTodo(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => editToDo(context, toDo),
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
              activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              value: toDo.isDone,
              onChanged: (_) { 
                final provider =
                      Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context, listen: false);
                  final isDone = provider.toggleTodoStatus(toDo);

                  Utils.showSnackBar(
                    context,
                    isDone ? 'Task completed' : 'Task marked incomplete',
                  );},
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    toDo.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (toDo.description.isNotEmpty)
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                      child: Text(
                        toDo.description,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, height: 1.5),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ));
}

  Void deleteToDo(BuildContext context, ToDo todo) {
    final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context, listen: false);
    provider.removeTodo(todo);

    Utils.showSnackBar(context, 'Deleted the task');
  }

 Void editToDo(BuildContext context, ToDo todo) => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => editToDoPage(Todo: todo),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter "this function has a return type of void and cannot be used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226568/flutter-this-function-has-a-return-type-of-void-and-cannot-be-used)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SlidableAction(
   onPressed: (context) => deleteToDo(context,toDo),
   backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
   foregroundColor: Colors.white,
   icon: Icons.delete,
   label: 'Delete',
)
```

Comment: thank you for looking at this for me. Unfortunately still no luck when adding () => deleteToDo(context,toDo), it displays the same error :(

Comment: The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(BuildContext)?'.